# loop to test all NFS mount point

Tags: linux, bash, nfs

this code work very well

```
mountpoint="/mnt/testnfs"
read -t1 < <(stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-)
if [ -z "$REPLY" ] ; then
echo "NFS mount stale. Removing..."
fi
```

If I try to put it into a loop for :

```
declare -a nfs_array=( "/mnt/testnfs1" "/mnt/testnfs2/" )

for i in "${nfs_array[@]}"
    do
        read -t1 < <(stat -t "$nfs_array" 2>&-)
        if [ -z "$REPLY" ] ; then
            echo "NFS dead"
        fi 
done
```

Aim is to test all mounts points, this code test and read only the first entries from nfs_array. If I swapped testnfs1 with testnfs2 this code will test testnfs2 mount point and forget testnfs1 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop it should be:

```
read -r -t1 < <(stat -t "$i" 2>&-)
```

Currently it's just reading the first array value and `$i` isn't used.

Comment: @jimbolino: You're welcome! Please mark answer as correct if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to  list **all** nfs mounts (the title tells so), then use either:

```
mount | grep ' type nfs' | ...
```

This may have false positives because a mount point or mounted path contains `type nfs`.

If the /proc/ file system is available, this is a better way:

```
awk '$3 ~ /^nfs/ {print}' /proc/mounts | ...
```

Here I'm not sure what happens, if mount point or mounted path contains a space -- I never had this situation.